# Problema al extraer fecha de publicación via xpath de un sitio

Tags: html5, xml, xpath

Tengo este sitio [sitio](http://www.enfokedirecto.com/magazine/sociedad/medicina___salud/estres_laboral___como_enfrentar_este_problema_/962) que extraigo su fecha de publicación via XPATH, utilizando por ejemplo la extension de Chrome [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl), el xpath seria : `//*[@id="content_texto"]/p[1]//text()` y me devuelve el resultado asi : `Publicado: Enero 28, 2019`

Lo que quiero es: que el Xpath me extraiga solo: `Enero 28, 2019`, ósea sin contener `Publicado:`, cómo seria el Xpath para extraer solo esa parte del texto?, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `substring`. Indicando que tome la cadena de texto a partir del carácter 21 en adelante.

`substring(//*[@id="content_texto"]/p[1]//text(),'21')`

En XPath Helper funciona correctamente

Aquí tiene las documentación de la [función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/XPath/Funciones/substring).

¿Porque desde el carácter 21?. Porque tiene espacios antes del publicado. Una opción para sacarle los espacios es la siguiente:

`substring(normalize-space(//*[@id="content_texto"]/p[1]//text()),12)`

Comment: Gracias Marcelo, es realmente lo que queria, eres un crack

Comment: Estimado marcelo, haber me puedes ayudar con esta pregunta parecida, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235882/invertir-valores-capturados-via-xpath-de-un-sitio-web, gracias