# Invertir Valores capturados via XPATH de un sitio web

Tags: html, html5, xml, xpath

Tengo este sitio, [Cronicaviva](http://www.cronicaviva.com.pe/fiscales-interrogaran-a-funcionarios-de-odebrecht-el-14-en-brasil/) que extraigo con una extension de Chrome [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl), el xpath que me extrae la fecha es: `//time//text()`, y como resultado me da: `Publicado el 06-02-2019`, tal como esta en el sitio.
Lo que quiero es como puedo invertir el formato de fecha que me trae?, ósea que me invierta el dia por el mes asi:`Publicado el 02-06-2019`, asi seria legible para mi, que significa 6 de febrero del 2019, asi como me trae dice 2 de junio del 2019.
NOTA: Solo usando el Xpath, sin ninguna otra herramienta extra

Answer (score 0):

Lo he hecho de esta forma con substring y concat: `concat(substring(//time//text(), 17, 2),'-',substring(//time//text(), 14, 2), '-', substring(//time//text(), 20, 4))` y funciona correctamente